# Odd unknown error with Zend_Loader_PluginLoader::setIncludeFileCache()

Tags: php, zend-framework

Ok. Here is my code:

```
    $classFileIncCache = BASE_PATH.'/public/cache/pluginLoaderCache.php';
    if (file_exists($classFileIncCache)) {
        include_once $classFileIncCache;
    }
    Zend_Loader_PluginLoader::setIncludeFileCache($classFileIncCache);
```

Now, it works great except, a single unknown error keeps getting written to my logs:

```
2010-12-16 09:11:05: Unknown error (ErrNo=2): include_once(Zend/Filter/Word\CamelCaseToDash.php) [<a href='function.include-once'>function.include-once</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/abcabc/abcabc.com/myapp/src/public/cache/pluginLoaderCache.php on line 9
2010-12-16 09:11:05: Unknown error (ErrNo=2): include_once() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening 'Zend/Filter/Word\CamelCaseToDash.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/abcabc/abcabc.com/lib/../thirdparty/src/Zend/library/:/var/www/abcabc/abcabc.com/lib/../myapp/src//library') in /var/www/abcabc/abcabc.com/myapp/src/public/cache/pluginLoaderCache.php on line 9
```

Upon further investigation I noticed this line in the cache file is problematic:

```
include_once 'Zend/Filter/Word\CamelCaseToDash.php';
```

All other lines are correct, with only forward slashes, for instance:

```
include_once 'Zend/View/Helper/HeadMeta.php';
include_once 'Zend/View/Helper/HeadLink.php';
include_once 'Zend/View/Helper/HeadScript.php';
include_once 'Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/ViewRenderer.php';
include_once 'Zend/Application/Resource/Frontcontroller.php';
include_once 'Zend/View/Helper/Doctype.php';
```

Is this a Zend Framework bug or could an error on my side be causing this?

Comment: @Richard: that '\' seems to be weird to me try to remove it from the source

Comment: @RageZ It will be put there back by Zend Framework. I am not addign manually anything to the file, it's Zend. Seems like a bug to me. Application works fine, because it is not a fatal error though.

Comment: @Richar: if you are sure this is a bug try to post it to their jira issue tracker

Comment: try to replace `/` with `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ` like that `include_once 'Zend'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Filter' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'Word' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'CamelCaseToDash.php';`

Comment: @tawfekov I did not write the code in that file. All includes where written by ZF. It's the plugin loader cache file.

Comment: I raised this as a bug more than a year ago. Try voting for it - http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-8429

Comment: @Phil Brown I have voted for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I literally just had this. It arose when I FTP'd files from my Windows machine to my Linux server. Delete the file and Zend will recreate it with the correct Directory Seperators as tawfeko suggests

Comment: Certainly, this is very annoying. I voted up thebug in ZF tracking site.